# unity EditorWindow#Focus cannot trigger OnFocus

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my code:

```
public class RoEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private static RoEditorWindow win;

    [MenuItem("Window/Ro Editor Window %g")]
    static void St()
    {
        if (!win)
        {
            win = EditorWindow.GetWindow<RoEditorWindow>();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Run focus");
            win.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void OnFocus()
    {
        Debug.Log("win focus");
    }
}
```

see my gif, if I use mouse click other win and click my win, OnFocus will work, but if I use my shortcut "ctrl+g", code `Debug.Log("Run focus")` is executed but #OnFocus is not triggered(see my gif unity editor console output)
[image]

the bad thing is if win#focus cannot focus, RoEditorWindow#OnGUI key listener will not work

so how to focus editorwindow in script like click editorwindow

my unity editor version is 2017.4.10 in linux

Answer (score 0):

**OnFocus is an event called when the window gains focus**. It is not called whenever you call Focus. In your example, the window already has the focus when you call Focus, so OnFocus is not called.

Comment: the key point is not OnFocus is not called, the key point is when i use win#focus, my key listener in win#OnGUI still doesn't work like not focus, I hope make key listener work